# Id being posted is always the Id from first row of table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

MVC 5 project. Working with a modal view. The modal has 2 parts. At the top is a dropdownlist with an "add" button. Below that is the main table, with row-delete capability (as described below). How it's supposed to work: If the user click's "add" the entry goes into the table. This works fine. I'm trying to get the row-specific delete functionality working now. Let me describe the issue....

I basically have a table with many items and a delete button for each row. The rows are created as such...

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
           @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Filter.Filter1)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
         <tr>
            <td>
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Filter.Filter1)
            </td>
         <td>
         @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteFromModal", "carColorsFilters", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <b>@item.Id</b>
                @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
                @Html.Hidden("carColorId", (Int32)ViewBag.carColorId)
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Delete" />
            }
          </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

My post action is defined as...

```
        public ActionResult DeleteFromModal(int id, int carColorId)
    {
        carColorsFilter carColorsFilter = db.carColorsFilters.Find(id);
        db.carColorsFilters.Remove(carColorsFilter);
        db.SaveChanges();


        ViewBag.carColorId = carColorId;
        ViewBag.FilterId = new SelectList(db.Filters, "Id", "Filter1");
        var carColorsfilters = db.carColorsFilters
                .Where(a => a.carColorId == carColorId)
                .Include(a => a.carColor)
                .Include(a => a.Filter);
        return View("_Index", carColorsfilters.ToList());
    }
```

This view is presented as a modal pop up.

When the modal first loads, I double checked the HTML hidden fields for ID (using View Source), and they are all correct. BUT, when I click on the delete button, regardless of the row, the ID of the FIRST row is always passed to the action.

Then, if I immediately check the HTML hidden fields again, ALL of the hidden fields for ID are the EXACT SAME, which is the ID of the ORIGINAL first row (which was deleted in the original delete click), so an error occurs.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Here's the source code for the modal actions...

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


    $(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {
            // hide dropdown if any (this is used wehen invoking modal from link in bootstrap dropdown )
            //$(e.target).closest('.btn-group').children('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');

            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#replacetarget').load(result.url); //  Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element
                    } else {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm(dialog);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "Second time" ?

Comment: @Shyju The table shows up perfect. 3 rows, all with individual ids and delete button, etc. I click delete and it runs the action fine, and the row disappears. I click delete on another row and it fails. The reason why is that the item.id being passed to the controller is the original one (which was deleted.)

Comment: Do you have some js code which is intercepting the delete form submit ?

Comment: @Shyju no I dont

Comment: Your code looks fine. It should send unique id numbers if `Model` is a collection of items with unique Id. Can you double check the view source and see whether the hidden input has unique id values ?

Comment: @Shyju On further investigation it appears that the id (for the row) that is being posted is always the original first row id. In other words, even though the hidden ids are showing up correctly, what is posted is always the same row id (from the first row.)

Comment: @Shyju I updated the question above to make it more accurate, after doing additional tests. It includes the answer to your question. Thanks!

Comment: Show how your displaying your modal. What are your scripts? Your code works fine assuming your displaying the correct modal associated with the row. And you have created a `SelectList` so what is your dropdownlist doing?

Comment: And as far as the `id` values when you return the view, that is because the `id` has been added to `ModelState` in the POST method. You can use `ModelState.Clear()` before your `return View(..)` statement to solve that.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I updated my original post with the code to load the modal. Any help would be appreciated. I'm so close to getting this working. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke in regards to the dropdownlist: The modal is pretty simple. Pretty much 2 parts. At the top is the dropdownlist with an "add" button. Below that is the main table (as described). If the user click's add it goes into the table. This works fine. I'm trying to get the row-specific delete functionality working now. I'll update the original post to say this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to  @StephenMuecke for your correct answer.

Once I did the ModelState.Clear() it seemed to work much better!

If you can tell me how to reward you with the answer please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely with these two lines:

```
@Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
@Html.Hidden("carColorId", (Int32)ViewBag.carColorId)
```

They are in a loop and the name of the hidden fields is being set to a static value (id and carColorId). This produces hidden fields with the same name each iteration, thus leading to your issue where the "first" id is always being passed to the action. As a side note, this is invalid as element IDs are meant to be unique for the entire document. Regardless, here's what I suggest you change:

```
@* Switch to a for loop to allow using the iterator variable to create
   unique names and ids for the fields *@
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)

@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].CarColorId)
```

I'm assuming that your Model is actually an IEnumerable, or similar, and that CarColorId is the name of the property on your model for the second hidden field - you'll want to fill it up in the controller, as opposed to using the ViewBag.

Hope that helps.

Comment: You may be correct as to the fields having the same names but your proposed answer does not work with the binding as with `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].Id)` you end up with `name="[1].Id"`, `name="[2].Id"` etc..

Comment: Excellent point @JudgeBread! I typically have collections like these in a separate property on the model, and not as the model itself, so I would have something like `m => m.myCollection[i].Id`

Comment: Duplicate `name` attributes are perfectly valid (although duplicate `id` attributes are not). But OP is creating a form in each iteration so it needs to generate `name="id"` so this cannot work

Answer (score 0):

[Sleeyuen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42961699/1453651)'s right that the duplicate names are causing the issue so I would personally take a different approach to you.

Have a single named hidden form on the page probably after your table.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteFromModal", "carColorsFilters", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "deleteFrm", id = "deleteFrm" }))
{
    @Html.Hidden("id", item.Id)
    @Html.Hidden("carColorId", (Int32)ViewBag.carColorId)
}
```

Your delete buttons should be only `button` types and have the id's to delete as `data-` attributes.

```
<input class="btn btn-primary deleteCarColorBtn" type="button" value="Delete" data-delete-id="item.id" data-car-color-id="(Int32)ViewBag.carColorId" />
```

Then on the click event of the button you can read the deleteid, pass it to your form and submit it.

```
var deleteId = $(".deleteCarColorBtn").data('deleteId');
var carColorId = $(".deleteCarColorBtn").data('carColorId');
$("#id").val(deleteId);
$("#carColorId").val(carColorId);
$("#deleteFrm").submit();
```